# Unable to connect to UNIX socket, Android

Tags: android, sockets, unix

I made a unix socket in C and i compiled it with ndk and through adb i pushed it in /data/local from my sd card. I changed permission of that file to 777 and execute it with ./ . Now i am able to see my own made socket in /dev/socket.

Now i am trying to connect this socket through the following JAVA code:

```
            mSocket = new LocalSocket();

            mSockAddr = new LocalSocketAddress( "rilproxy"  );
            mSocket.connect( mSockAddr );
```

I am getting following error:

java.io.IOException: Connection refused

I tried hard to workaround with this problem but with no luck. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Query:
1 Are you trying to open a socket connection from an Android app to the same Android device. 
2.Are you testing on device or on emulator ?

Comment: 1-yes 2-on device.

I am unable to get full stacktrace, just getting the mentioned error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, can you please post what was the solution? thx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given Internet permission in Android manifest file ? If not, given then your first socket connection itself would be failing.. (A properly coded android application which declares network permission in its manifest can accept connections on unpriveleged ports as there is no firewall on the device.)

Add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml

If testing on emulator then use use 10.0.2.2 in place of localhost (10.0.2.2 is the "magic" IP address you'd use if running the app in the emulator. )

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as i am not using ip sockets with ip and port numbers. I am using unix socket which is use to carry out ipc only and requires path only.

Comment: Are you sure that process has started listening by the time you try to connect? You may be running ahead of it.